# Can I add an object to the preposition in "sites that are more challenging to extract resources from"? What about removing "from" entirely?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-structure

> 1. I hate the sites that are more challenging to extract resources from their inside. (I made this sentence.)

I know people would normally say  the following version:

> 2. I hate the sites that are more challenging to extract resources **from.**

I want to know that if sentences 1  is so called redundant or just unacceptable/wrong.
And what about (3), where "from" is dropped along?

> 3. I hate the sites that are more challenging to extract resources.
>    (I made this sentence.）

Comment: Is 'mine' meant to be part of the sentence, or do you mean 'it's my sentence'?

Comment: @KateBunting   Thank you. That was the typo.  I have deleted it

Comment: It doesn't sound natural to refer to 'extracting resources from _inside_ a site' as though the website had a physical shape with an interior.

Comment: I am not still clear what *(I made)* means. Does it mean *This is the sentence I wrote.* or is it a parenthetical for *resources* to mean *the resources I made*?

Comment: I gave you and answer and you have not reacted. Did you see it? One way or another you must keep **from**. Dropping it is a typical non-native speaker mistake...

Comment: On a more nuanced issue, we would probably say "sites" without determiner, rather than "the sites", if you hadn't already distinguished between sites that area easy to extract information from and sites that are difficult in that respect.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice sites versus the sites is a matter of context. Like every other *plural [noun]* versus *the plural [noun]*. That was not the question here and it's been more-than-many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample: I hate the sites that are more challenging to extract resources from their inside mine. (I made)

to extract resources from a site=phrasing

That then gives us:
I hate the mines [or sites] *from which* it is more challenging to extract resources.

Written English and more formal [above]

I hate the mines [or sites] that are more challenging to extract resources *from*.

Informal and spoken.

The sites are the mines, so it's better to just say that.

Comment: Thanks, I get it

Comment: Note that OP removed "mine" from the sentence in the question since it was a typo.

Comment: @Laurel sites or mines work the same way.

Comment: @ForOU We say write a sentence or make up a sentence.

Comment: You don't answer OP's question whether sentence #1 is "redundant or just unacceptable/wrong". You've given two correct forms of the sentence, but you don't say that #1 is wrong, and if so, why it is wrong.

Comment: It is not necessary. Generally, if you present the correct form that is enough. Why bother with egregious mistakes that one must bend over backwards to explain grammatically? The basic thing here that was missed was: to extract resources from a site. Anyway, the OP understood my explanation.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice There's no point in trying to prove a negative. The way I gave my explanation starting with "to extract resources from a site" as the basis for  from which or from at the end is quite sufficient.